# NestJS Testing: decorator is not a function

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, decorator, nestjs

My dependencies:

```
"@nestjs/common": "7.4.4",
"@nestjs/core": "7.4.4",
"typescript": "4.0.2",
"jest": "26.4.2",
"jest-junit": "11.1.0",
"ts-jest": "26.3.0",
```

I have a custom decorator:

```js
import { Inject } from "@nestjs/common";

import { DATABASE_SERVICE } from "./database.constants";

export const InjectDatabase = () => Inject(DATABASE_SERVICE);
```

I use it in constructor for a service I'm willing to cover with tests:

```js
import {
  DatabaseService,
  InjectDatabase
} from "@infra/modules";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectDatabase() private readonly db: DatabaseService
  ) {}
}
```

here is how I setup testing module:

```js
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";

import { MyService } from "../../../src/shared/services/my.service";
import { SharedModule } from "../../../src/shared/shared.module";

describe(`MyService`, () => {
  let myService: MyService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [SharedModule]
    }).compile();

    myService = moduleRef.get<MyService>(MyService);
  });
  test("tests", () => {
    // console.log("test");
  });
});
```

SharedModule is a module with `@Global()` decorator and includes `MyService` in providers/exports.

When I try to execute my test, I get error:

```
TypeError: modules_1.InjectDatabase is not a function

      51 | 
      52 |   constructor(
    > 53 |     @InjectDatabase() private readonly adb_db: DatabaseService,
         |      ^
      56 |   ) {}

      at Object.<anonymous> (apps/workers/my/src/shared/services/my.service.ts:53:6)
      at Object.<anonymous> (apps/workers/my/test/shared/services/my.service.unit.test.ts:8:1)
```

I followed the trace and steps as you can see above:

- Import file with service in test:
  `import { MyService } from "../../../src/shared/services/my.service";`
- Raise error at `@InjectDatabase()` in constructor of service

If I switch from `@InjectDatabase` to `@Inject(DATABASE_SERVICE)`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DATABASE_SERVICE) private readonly db: DatabaseService
  ) {}
}
```

I get another error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CacheService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

I tried to setup testing module like this:

```js
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [DatabaseModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: DATABASE_SERVICE,
          useClass: DatabaseService
        },
        MyService
      ]
    }).compile();
```

But it didn't help, same issue:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CacheService (?).
```

My `tsconfig.json` compiler options:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "sourceRoot": "/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
```

I have in `jest.config.js`:

```js
setupFiles: ["./jest-setup-file.ts"],
```

This file has only import of reflect lib:

```js
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

I tried to add to `my.service.ts` before `MyService` declaration:

```js
console.log('InjectDatabase', InjectDatabase)
```

and received:

```
InjectDatabase: undefined
```

So it seems either Jest cannot resolve imports o something is wrong with  typescript config.

Decorator function imported in `MyService` as:

```js
import {
  DatabaseService,
  InjectDatabase
} from "@infra/modules";
```

My `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  bail: 0,
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  roots: ["<rootDir>/libs", "<rootDir>/apps"],
  testRegex: ".*\\.test\\.ts$",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/dist/", "/build/"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "json"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@common": "<rootDir>/libs/common/src",
    "@common/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/common/src/$1",
    "@infra": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src",
    "@infra/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src/$1"
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  setupFiles: ["./jest-setup-file.ts"],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: 80
    }
  },
  coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover"],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"]
};
```

Probably `moduleNameMapper` doesn't resolve correctly `"@infra/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src/$1"` for `"@infra/modules"`?

Outside of tests - everything works as intended.

How can I setup correctly jest/typescript/nest so my custom decorators recognized correctly?

Comment: I don’t understand the way you write your custom decorator. Did you try with the createParamDecorator method, as in documentation ? https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators

Comment: @Seraf Well, I tried to do this way to, but seems jest cannot resolve path to the module with the function and ends with having it as undefined.

Comment: Any chance you can provide a minimum reproduction? I haven't had a problem before using custom decorators and testing them.

Answer (score 2):

After a better debugging I found that Jest somehow doesn't resolve path aliases with sub folders to  module, and instead of loading imported content it return undefined.
Settings in jest.config.js:

```json
    "@infra": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src",
    "@infra/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src/$1"
```

So second line from above doesn't work with Jest.
All imports which had path like:
`import Stuff from "@infra/sub/folder/module"`
were returning `undefined`
when paths like:
`import Stuff from "@infra`
worked like a charm.

I fixed barrel files in `@infra` lib to correctly export stuff and fixed imports to use shorten path and it helped to resolve the issue.

I'm still curious why setting for Jest:
`"@infra/(.*)": "<rootDir>/libs/infrastructure/src/$1"`
under:
`moduleNameMapper`
doesn't work.